# Consulta $.get json e mostrar resultado

Tags: php, json

Estou enviando um array para um consulta em um banco MySQL via $.getJSON e no php  monto uma tabela, mas não estou conseguindo retornar e fazer a exibição dessa tabela, como posso fazer isso?

O meu código que envia os parâmetros está assim:

```
         // Gravação e mensagem no retorno do cadastro do comentário
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnImprimeLista").click(function () {

            var nChecked = new Array();

            $("input[name='check[]']:checked").each(function () {
                nChecked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
            });

            $.getJSON(
                'imprimetodoslista.php', {
                    list: nChecked
                },
                function (json) {
                console.log(json);
                // Mostrar a tabela no retorno      
                }
            );
        });
    });
```

O PHP está assim:

```
// Consultando candidados no banco
foreach($checkboxes as $id) {

    mysql_select_db($database_con, $con);
    $query_rsRegistro = "SELECT nome, email, celular, id_municipio, id_uf, dt_nascimento FROM candidato WHERE id_candidato = '$id'";
    $rsRegistro = mysql_query($query_rsRegistro, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro);
    $totalRows_rsRegistro = mysql_num_rows($rsRegistro);

    $Nome = $row_rsRegistro['nome'];
    $Email = $row_rsRegistro['email'];
    $Celular = $row_rsRegistro['celular'];
    $Municipio = $row_rsRegistro['id_municipio'];
    $UF = $row_rsRegistro['id_uf'];
    $Nascimento = $row_rsRegistro['dt_nascimento'];

    $tabela = "     
     <table width=100%  border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1>
      <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>E-mail</td>
        <td>Celular</td>
        <td>Municipio</td>
        <td>UF</td>
        <td>Nascimento</td>
      </tr>";            
    do {            
      $tabela .= "
      <tr>
        <td>{$Nome}; </td>
        <td>{$Email}; </td>
        <td>{$Celular}; </td>
        <td>{$Municipio};</td>
        <td>{$UF};</td>
        <td>{$Nascimento};</td>     
      </tr>";
    } while ($row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro)); 
    $tabela .= "</table>";  

}

$arr['msg'] = $tabela;      

$arr = array_map('htmlentities',$arr);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no retorno do código, você está usando a função getJSON, neste caso o valor do PHP deve ser retornado via JSON e não como um HTML.

Da maneira que você está usando, mude a função de getJSON para $.get (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) ou então retorne os valores em JSON sem o HTML passando apenas os resultados/array (http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) para que o JavaScript possa interpretar o retorno.

```
json_encode($row_rsRegistro);
```

Espero ter lhe ajudado.

Comment: Excelente dica, muito obrigado @Marcus V. Nash.